# a tag doesn't effected by class

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

i'm using laravel and i'm trying to make active class but the a tag does not affected by the class

here's my blade:

```
<li class="{{ (request()->is('categories*')) ? 'side-active' : '' }}">
            <a href="categories" >
                <i class='bx bx-circle'></i>
                <span class="links_name ">Kategori Produk</span>
            </a>
            <span class="tooltip">Kategori Produk</span>
        </li>
```

and here's my css:

```
.side-active {
    color: #009DA9 !important;
    border-left: 2px solid #009DA9;
}
```

it look like this:
[image]

but if i'm place the class inside span or i tag it change the color of the font:

```
<li class="">
                <a href="categories" >
                    <i class='bx bx-circle {{ (request()->is('categories*')) ? 'side-active' : '' }}'></i>
                    <span class="links_name {{ (request()->is('categories*')) ? 'side-active' : '' }}">Kategori Produk</span>
                </a>
                <span class="tooltip">Kategori Produk</span>
            </li>
```

but look like this:
[image]

i want it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: Most likely the `links_name` class is changing the color of the font, overriding 'side-active'. Check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad guys, i need to add more class like this on my css:

```
.side-active {
    border-left: 2px solid #009DA9;
}

.side-active span {
    color: #009DA9 !important;
}

.side-active i {
    color: #009DA9 !important;
}
```